# application/x-pdf vs pdf

Tags: pdf, webserver, mime-types

I am generating a document with latex in pdf (on linux). It works fine, but when I try to upload it online it says it is not a pdf but an application/x-pdf. How do I convert it to true pdf?

Comment: what do you mean? I am just a user of the website, I am not admistrator, is there anything I could do?

Answer (score 0):

well, I solved this problem switching to another browser (Chrome, I was using firefox) 
"Some versions of Firefox corrupt certain properties of the file". This question is very specific, but I leave it here, I hope it helps some other user in the future.